# Query several EAV attributes in separate columns

Tags: sql, entity-attribute-value

I am facing issues trying to write a query. (this is slightly modified from my previous question)

My tables are laid out as follows:

```
 tblTicketIssues.TicketID
 tblTicketIssues.RequesterID

 tblPersonnelProfile.PersonnelID
 tblPersonnelProfile.FirstName
 tblPersonnelProfile.LastName

 tblTicketAttribute.TicketID
 tblTicketAttribute.Attribute
 tblTicketAttribute.AttributeValue
```

I have to display the following fields:

```
 TicketID, RequesterFullName, UrgentPriorityID, MediumPriorityID, 
 LowPrioritytID
```

This is the part that is challenging:

If tblTicketAttribute.Attribute= "Urgent" then the value from tblTicketAttribute.AttributeValue is displayed in UrgentPriority column

If tblTicketAttribute.Attribute= "Medium" then the value from tblTicketAttribute.AttributeValue is displayed in MediumPriority column

If tblTicketAttribute.Attribute= "Low" then the value from tblTicketAttribute.AttributeValue is displayed in LowPriority column

If tblTicketAttribute.Attribute= "Closed" then

The values in tblTicketAttribute.Attribute include "Urgent", "Medium", "Low", "Over30", "Over60", "Over90", "Closed"

I don't need to display all records. Only "Urgent", "Medium" & "Low".

Comment: This question could really stand to have a better (more descriptive) title and some additional appropriate tags.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand, but I think this satisfies what you're asking for. Note that this was assuming that the database is MySQL, you didn't specify. The syntax of the IF() and CONCAT() may be slightly different if it's something else.

*EDIT: updated query as per Csharp's "answer" below. `MAX`-ing the name is a bit of a hack.*

```
SELECT t.TicketID,
    MAX(CONCAT(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName)) AS RequesterFullName,
    MAX(IF(a.Attribute = 'Urgent', a.AttributeValue, NULL)) AS UrgentPriorityID,
    MAX(IF(a.Attribute = 'Medium', a.AttributeValue, NULL)) AS MediumPriorityID,
    MAX(IF(a.Attribute = 'Low', a.AttributeValue, NULL)) AS LowPriorityID
FROM tblTicketIssues AS t
    LEFT JOIN tblPersonnelProfile AS p ON p.PersonnelID = t.RequesterID
    LEFT JOIN tblTicketAttribute AS a ON a.TicketID = t.TicketID
WHERE a.Attribute IN ('Urgent', 'Medium', 'Low')
GROUP BY t.TicketID;
```

Answer (score 2):

The database design uses the [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eav) pattern for the `tblTicketAttribute` table.  The difficulty you faced trying to get this rather ordinary query result shows how EAV causes a lot of problems.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663040/query-several-eav-attributes-in-separate-columns/663074#663074) by @Chad Birch is one way to get the result.  Here's another way to get the result you want:

```
SELECT t.TicketID,
    CONCAT(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName) AS RequesterFullName,
    a1.AttributeValue AS UrgentPriorityID,
    a2.AttributeValue AS MediumPriorityID,
    a3.AttributeValue AS LowPriorityID
FROM tblTicketIssues AS t
  JOIN tblPersonnelProfile AS p ON (p.PersonnelID = t.RequesterID)
  LEFT JOIN tblTicketAttribute AS a1 
    ON (a1.TicketID = t.TicketID AND a1.Attribute = 'Urgent')
  LEFT JOIN tblTicketAttribute AS a2 
    ON (a2.TicketID = t.TicketID AND a2.Attribute = 'Medium')
  LEFT JOIN tblTicketAttribute AS a3 
    ON (a3.TicketID = t.TicketID AND a3.Attribute = 'Low');
```

This solution uses no `GROUP BY` clause, but it does require a separate `JOIN` for each attribute you want to retrieve.

Yet another solution is to fetch attributes on multiple rows of the result set:

```
SELECT t.TicketID,
    CONCAT(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName) AS RequesterFullName,
    a.AttributeValue AS AnyPriorityID
FROM tblTicketIssues AS t
  JOIN tblPersonnelProfile AS p ON (p.PersonnelID = t.RequesterID)
  LEFT JOIN tblTicketAttribute AS a 
    ON (a1.TicketID = t.TicketID AND a.Attribute IN ('Urgent', 'Medium', 'Low'));
```

This solution scales better as an SQL query, because you don't have to add more `JOIN` clauses as you fetch more attributes.  But it does mean you have to do some post-processing of the result set in your application code, to get it into the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you want to do it this way, but here goes (assuming SQL Server):

```
 SELECT TicketID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS RequestFullName,
 CASE WHEN Attribute = "Low" THEN AttributeValue ELSE "" END AS LowPriorityID,
 CASE WHEN Attribute = "Medium" THEN AttributeValue ELSE "" END AS MediumPriorityID,
 CASE WHEN Attribute = "Urgent" THEN AttributeValue ELSE "" END AS UrgentPriorityID
 FROM ...
 WHERE Attribute IN ("Urgent", "Low", "Medium")
```

But that seems like a bizarre way to do things to me.

Can you clarify if the relationship between tbTicketIssues and tbTicketAttributes is one-to-one, or one-to-many?

Answer (score 0):

One relatively straightforward way to do something like this would be to just union three queries together.  I suspect that what you're looking for would be something like this:

```
SELECT i.TicketID, a.FirstName, pp.AttributeValue AS UrgentPriorityID, null AS MediumPriorityID, null AS LowPrioritytID
FROM tblTicketIssues i, tblTicketAttribute a, tblPersonnelProfile pp
WHERE i.RequesterID = a.PersonnelID
AND i.TicketID = pp.TicketID
AND pp.Attribute = "Urgent"
UNION
SELECT i.TicketID, a.FirstName, null AS UrgentPriorityID, pp.AttributeValue AS MediumPriorityID, null AS LowPrioritytID
FROM tblTicketIssues i, tblTicketAttribute a, tblPersonnelProfile pp
WHERE i.RequesterID = a.PersonnelID
AND i.TicketID = pp.TicketID
AND pp.Attribute = "Medium"
UNION
SELECT i.TicketID, a.FirstName, null AS UrgentPriorityID, null AS MediumPriorityID, pp.AttributeValue AS LowPrioritytID
FROM tblTicketIssues i, tblTicketAttribute a, tblPersonnelProfile pp
WHERE i.RequesterID = a.PersonnelID
AND i.TicketID = pp.TicketID
AND pp.Attribute = "Low"
```

(this is SQL Server btw, though I doubt it would be much different on pretty much any RDBMS)

There are doubtless "slicker" ways that this could be done, but I like this way because it's very straightforward when reading it.